# creating a remote sharedObject using amazon cloudFront

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, amazon-cloudfront, shared-objects

I am trying to create a remote sharedObject on amazon cloudFront using Flash (AS2). I tried to find the url for the rmtp connection and I think it is correct. But I get netConnection Failed and other times netConnection Rejected trace messages.

This is my code

```
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.onStatus = function(info) {
        trace("Level: "+info.level+"  "+info.code+" ");
    };
    nc.connect("rtmp:/somecodesfromamazon.cloudfront.net");
    mySO = SharedObject.getRemote("mySO", nc.uri, true);
    mySO.connect(nc);
```

I am new to Amazon cloudfront. I looked online and I read that I have to have a bucket and a folder for my application. But my application resides on the machine, my machine. I am basically the client and I need this sharedObject to update the values from an application that I have on several computers. In other words,the sharedObject just helps me keep track of the data on several machines.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: rtmp url does not look right. Did you miss a slash, or is it lost during pasting here?

Comment: I tried using double slash but that did not work either. I eventually gave up. I could not find where I would create the folder after the app name. Thank you for the answer though